# Поделиться содержимым WebView в pdf

Tags: java, android

У меня есть WebView, содержание которого я формирую из локального txt, даю ему необходимые настройки.
В принципе, по вот этой [инструкции](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_HTML_and_Web_Content_Printing_Example) я формирую из содержимого WebView pdf и отправляю его на печать или на сохрание в локальном хранилище.
Как сделать так, чтобы pdf отправлялся не для печати или сохранения в локальное хранилище, а появлялось окно с мессенджерами, почтой и вообще всеми приложениями, через которые можно поделиться файлами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть такой пример:

```
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "your_file.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

activity.startActivity(share);
```

вам нужно только поменять определение пути файла так как вероятнее всего вы его храните где-то в другом месте отличном от загрузочной папки. Дальше все через интент делается. Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) по работе с Intent. Так же есть [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673238/send-a-pdf-file-as-mail-or-offer-app-to-directly-view-the-file) вариант:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(reportFile), "application/pdf")));
```

вам нужно определить путь к файлу а дальше все предельно просто.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Но это не то, пожалуй. Я хочу отправить не локальный файл, а сформированный текст с параметрами, которые я задал ему WebView. Лучше всего, чтобы он был преобразован в pdf

Comment: а как вы хотите отправить то чего нет? вам нужно сначала его экспортировать в файл, а потом этот файл отправить. Вы написали что вы формируете pdf но где вы его потом храните? можно после отправки файл удалить если вам это так важно

Comment: Pdf формируется "на лету". Есть html , который можно отправить на печать или сохранить как pdf

Comment: так сохраните в чем проблема, в папке приложения а дальше отправляйте куда вам нужно, или вам нужно как-то без сохранения это реализовать?

Comment: спасибо за подсказку логики этого процесса. так и сделаю - сохраню webview в pdf, а потом удалю, чтобы не засорять хранилище

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.